# Thunk testing using mockStore with getState()

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-mock-store

I am having trouble testing a thunk using mock-store.

In my thunk I call getState() to get the state of the redux store and then dispatch actions based on the state.

How do I get my thunks getState() call to check the mock stores state and not the redux store state?

```
    import {initialState} from '../configureStore'
    import {saveAndSendTask} from '../thunks/queueThunk'
    import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
    import * as actions from '../actions/index'

    const middlewares = [thunk]
    const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)

    describe('Testing TaskQueue Thunk', () => {
        const store = mockStore(initialState)

        test('Test TaskQueue thunk sends to sever and removes from queue.', () => {
            // removed variables test data for the sake of brevity.

            // Add actions to Mock Store and set up Base state needed to test.
            store.dispatch(actions.addToTaskQueue(task1))
            store.dispatch(actions.addToTaskQueue(task2))
            store.dispatch(actions.setTasks([task1, task2, task3]))
            store.dispatch(actions.selectTask(task3.id))
            store.dispatch(actions.isConnected(true))

            // This is the thunk I want to test.
            store.dispatch(saveAndSendTask())

            expect('something').toEqual('something')
        })
    )}
```

Here is the thunk I want to test.

```
    export const saveAndSendTask = (): any => {
      return (dispatch: Dispatch, getState) => {

        // This state is the same as initial state of redux store. Ignores Mock store state.
        console.log(getState())

        // Selected task is undefined.
        dispatch(addToTaskQueue(getState().tasks.selectedTask))

        // ....rest of logic.....
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `redux-mock-store` does not update the state but only records the actions passed to the dispatch.

Additionally, the code implementing the `getState` method in the library either returns the initial state passed or a function.

```
getState () {
  return isFunction(getState) ? getState(actions) : getState
}
```

According to the documentation:

> Please note that this library is designed to test the action-related logic, not the reducer-related one. In other words, it does not update the Redux store.
>    If you want a complex test combining actions and reducers together,
>   take a look at other libraries (e.g., redux-actions-assertions). Refer
>   to issue [#71](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store/issues/71) for more details.

You can either try another library, follow the recommendation noted in #71 by passing the actions to your reducer manually to get the updated state that you were expecting, or modify your spec to validate the action dispatched in `saveAndSendTask` using the expected previous state to initialize your mockStore.